# PHP - search in array and create new one

Tags: php, arrays

I want to avoid if it is possible **foreach** combined with if. I want to search the array, take out the matches and create new one base on result.

In this example I want to create separate arrays for each **os** -

```
$os1 = $array;
$os2 = $array...
```

Array looks like this:

```
    $array = [
            0 => [
                'id'   => 1,
                'name' => 'name',
                'os'   => 1
            ],
            1 => [
                'id'   => 2,
                'name' => 'name',
                'os'   => 1
            ],
            2 => [
                'id'   => 3,
                'name' => 'name',
                'os'   => 2
            ],
            3 => [
                'id'   => 3,
                'name' => 'name',
                'os'   => 2             
            ]
    ];
```

Comment: why do you want to avoid foreach? - also try to re-write your question without using 'for each' ;)

Comment: I think you can use the function `array_map`

Comment: What is your desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use array_filter to reduce the input array to the expected result

```
$os = 1;
$data = array_filter($array, function($item) use ($os) {
    return $item['os'] == $os;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The short one

```
$os1 = [];
$os2 = [];
$os3 = [];

foreach ($array as $item) {
    ${'os' . $item['os']}[] = array('id' => $item['id'], 'name' => $item[$name];
}
```

The better one

```
$os1 = [];
$os2 = [];
$os3 = [];

foreach ($array as $item) {
    switch($item['os']) {
        case 1:
            $os1[] = array('id' => $item['id'], 'name' => $item[$name]);
            break;
        case 2:
            $os2[] = array('id' => $item['id'], 'name' => $item[$name]);
            break;
        case 3:
            $os3[] = array('id' => $item['id'], 'name' => $item[$name]);
            break;
        default:
            throw new Exception('Unknown Os');
    }
}
```

Also you maybe want to assign `array($item['id'] => $item[$name]);` instead of `array('id' => $item['id'], 'name' => $item[$name]);`

```
$os1 = [];
$os2 = [];
$os3 = [];

foreach ($array as $item) {
    ${'os' . $item['os']}[] = array($item['id'] => $item[$name]);
}
```